# Get formula value XLSX file by Java POI API

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an external XLSX file like this:
[image]

my objective is this:

when I write in C6 cell, XLSX file calculate new value for D7 cell, when I write in C7 cell, XLSX file calculate new value for D8 cell and so on.

My problem is that when I write in C6 cell, for example, I want to get the new value calculated for D7 cell but I'm not able to do it.

The code I develop now is this:

```
File myFile = new File("testfile.xlsx"); 
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(2);
XSSFCell cella =  mySheet.getRow(5).getCell(2); // C6 cell
cella.setCellValue("L"); // write 'L' in C6 cell
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
myWorkBook.write(os);
```

After to write in C6 cell, for example, I tried to get value in D7 cell by this way:

```
mySheet.getRow(6).getCell(3).getNumericCellValue()
```

but I get `"0.0"`

Can you help me please?

EDITED ONE:

I dont know the formula used for calculate the D column, if I click on D6 cell I get this:[image]

Comment: Is there a formula to calculate the value for `D` cells ? and are you using it to setting the value ?

Comment: I do not work with Apache but can you check for me what `mySheet.getRow(6).getCell(3).getRichStringCellValue()` give you?

Comment: I edited the question @svasa

Comment: I edited the question @SiddharthRout

Comment: @SiddharthRout if I use your code I get empty string on console

Comment: What about `.getRawValue()` or `getStringCellValue()`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout user needs to set the value by using `setCellValue` otherwise it returns default

Comment: Try this `FormulaEvaluator evaluator = myWorkBook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();` and then 
`XSSFCell formulaCell = mySheet.getRow(6).getCell(3);` and then 
`CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(formulaCell);` and then 
`System.out.println(cellValue.getNumberValue());`

Comment: both return empty string in console

Comment: I am trying to self educate here and try to help you at the same time. Did you try the set of code that I posted in the last comment?

Comment: Multiple issues here: 1. Screenshots are not `Excel` but Openoffice `Calc`. 2. The formula `=$algoritmo.C6` is only a reference to cell `C6` in sheet named "algoritmo". So the right formula ist there and so the `FormulaEvaluator ` must evaluate this cell first or [all formulas in the whole workbook must be evaluated](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#Recalculation+of+Formulas) before reading the evaluated cell value. Main misunderstanding seems to be that `apache poi` is **not** providing automatic calculation chain as `Excel` may do.